# Why does Blender rotate my images 90 degrees on import?

Tags: image, import

I just don't understand why this happens? No other program does this on my computer, but when I try to import a image, Blender rotates the images 90 degrees to the left, causing me to do extra work every time i need one.[image]

On the left side, you'll see the Blender import file window, on the right side, just windows explorer, which clearly shows correct.

Comment: Most likely because that rotation information is saved as EXIF metadata from the phone camera or whatever snapped those pictures, rather than actual pixel information. I'd be inclined to conclude that Blender doesn't yet read EXIF rotation information

Comment: Alright, thanks. This seems to be the problem.